# Cannot walk directory using Files.walk

Tags: java, java-io

I am trying to understand why my code won't run.

The example is how to use `java.io` to find a path directory and print out the title of all `.txt` files in that directory.

My code is below:

```
try 
    {
        Files.walk(Paths.get(\\Users\\Name\\Desktop\\Test Folder)).forEach(p -> {
            if (p.getFileName().toString().endsWith(".txt")) {
                System.out.println("Text doc: " + p.getFileName());
            }
        });
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I am currently importing `java.io.IOException`, `java.nio.file.Files`, and `java.nio.file.Paths`.

The error I am getting is `java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: myDirPath`.

If anyone can help, or at least point me in the right direction I would be very grateful.

Comment: Does the path in `myDirPath` exist?

Comment: It's actually not a real variable. I just put that there for the post. I copy the path directly from my folder in question and paste it.

Comment: Following proper Java string escaping semantics, as seen in the example code?

Comment: Yeah, I did. That's why I am confused haha. The section ends after this point and I don't want to move on without feeling I have the slightest understanding as to why I am struggling with this

Comment: Hard to say--if it says there's no such file, it seems like there might not be such a file. It would be easier to help if you posted the complete code, and the data you're using--you can create a fake directory if you don't want to post sensitive directory information.

Comment: Unrelated: the example code you're not running isn't helpful--just post a minimal, complete example. In this case the entire code is essentially what you have, plus the class wrapper and imports--might as well just post the whole thing.

Comment: "//Users//Name//Desktop//Test Folder" is what I have. I also made two files (textfile1.txt, textfile2.txt) in my "Test Folder". I am using a mac and have tried both // and \\ which is used in the example.

Comment: Unrelated: Will do! Thank you for also editing out the unnecessary information in my question and title. Trying to over explain something can just make the problem harder to pinpoint.

Comment: @basketstheclown - the problem is simply the doubling up of slashes. You seem to misunderstand; it is neccessary for backslashes because backslash is used in strings for escaping things. You do NOT double up the forward slashes. Just put `"/Users/Name/Desktop/Test Folder"`.

Comment: Those are forward slashes, not backward slashes; you don't need to escape forward slashes (assuming you're on OS X). Since you're on OS X it's probably not as important, but I always sanity-check by not having any spaces in the directory name to eliminate that as a culprit. Generally more of an issue on Windows machines, but I don't run Java on Windows anymore, so no clue if that's still a thing.

Comment: @basketstheclown Re: editing--no problem; it's not always obvious what's important and what isn't. In general, on SO, *only* the explictly-technical stuff counts... like the data you're using (in this case, the dir name string :)

Comment: I feel dumb. That did it. Still looking over the "little things". Thank you for your time. Do I delete this question, or close it out?

Comment: @basketstheclown Up to you :) I might edit it to remove the example code, include the string you were using, and self-answer it with the solution, and when you're able to, accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
try 
    {
        Files.walk(Paths.get("/Users/Jayden/Desktop/Test Folder")).forEach(p -> {
            if (p.getFileName().toString().endsWith(".txt")) {
                System.out.println("Text doc: " + p.getFileName());
            }
        });
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I was not using slashes properly.